# Is there a way I can get selective data from strings like these?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am working on a program which fetches strings like these:

```
s = 'GPA: 3.4 GRE: 317 Round: Round 2 | West'
d = 'GPA: 3.7 GRE: 328 Round: Round 3 | Singapore'
a = 'GPA: undergrad: 3.68 grad: DPT 3.32 GMAT Waiver Round: Round 3'
c = 'GPA: 3.2 GMAT: 750 Round: Rolling Admissions | NY'
```

Until now I was just fetching the number of rounds using re expressions.
But for some exceptions like c, I need to get it to return 'rolling admissions' as well. Is there a way to get data between round and the pipe sign?

I had been doing like this:

```
R = re.findall('\S*Round ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', d)
print(''.join(R))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex below gets the value between the two delimters `Round:`  and  `|`

```
import re

c = 'GPA: 3.2 GMAT: 750 Round: Rolling Admissions | NY'
R = re.findall('Round\: (.*?) \|', c)
print(R) # output: 'Rolling Admissions'
```

Edit:
Noted that there are a few instance where the pipe sign isn't available. Using the following will search the string after `Round:`  and before  `|` or till the end of the string

```
import re

s = 'GPA: 3.4 GRE: 317 Round: Round 2 | West'
d = 'GPA: 3.7 GRE: 328 Round: Round 3 | Singapore'
a = 'GPA: undergrad: 3.68 grad: DPT 3.32 GMAT Waiver Round: Round 3'
c = 'GPA: 3.2 GMAT: 750 Round: Rolling Admissions | NY'

print(re.findall('Round: (.*?) ($|\|)', s)) #output: [('Round 2', '|')]
print(re.findall('Round: (.*?) ($|\|)', d)) #output: [('Round 3', '|')]
print(re.findall('Round: (.*?) ($|\|)', a)) #output: [('Round 3 ', '|')]
print(re.findall('Round: (.*?) ($|\|)', c)) #output: [('Rolling Admissions', '|')]
```

You will just need to get the first element and that will be your requested value

eg.

```
value = re.findall('Round: (.*?) ($|\|)', c)) #output: [('Rolling Admissions', '|')]
print(value[0][0]) # since the output is a tuple within a list
```

Comment: There are a few instances when the pipe sign isn't available in the end, what can be done in that case?

Comment: I am not able to get the answer for the third string (a). It is just blank

Comment: Apologies, this is because there is no space after 'Round 3' for string (a). removing the space will do, however, this will result in a space in the other results, which shouldnt be too hard to clean - `re.findall('Round: (.*?)($|\|)', a)` Sorry this is might not be the best solution

Answer (score 1):

here you go

```
c = 'GPA: 3.2 GMAT: 750 Round: Rolling Admissions | NY'
c.split('|')[0]
```